# Efficient way to restruct JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json

I receive input from one the API in the following format:

```
"annual": {
                    "Revenue": [
                        {
                            "date": "2020-06-30",
                            "value": "12820.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2019-06-30",
                            "value": "9965.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2018-06-30",
                            "value": "6887.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2017-06-30",
                            "value": "8447.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2016-06-30",
                            "value": "7083.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2015-06-30",
                            "value": "8574.000000"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Total Revenue": [
                        {
                            "date": "2020-06-30",
                            "value": "12820.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2019-06-30",
                            "value": "9965.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2018-06-30",
                            "value": "6887.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2017-06-30",
                            "value": "8447.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2016-06-30",
                            "value": "7083.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2015-06-30",
                            "value": "8574.000000"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Cost of Revenue, Total": [
                        {
                            "date": "2020-06-30",
                            "value": "5742.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2019-06-30",
                            "value": "5115.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2018-06-30",
                            "value": "4930.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2017-06-30",
                            "value": "4888.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2016-06-30",
                            "value": "5064.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2015-06-30",
                            "value": "7427.000000"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Gross Profit": [
                        {
                            "date": "2020-06-30",
                            "value": "7078.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2019-06-30",
                            "value": "4850.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2018-06-30",
                            "value": "1957.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2017-06-30",
                            "value": "3559.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2016-06-30",
                            "value": "2019.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2015-06-30",
                            "value": "1147.000000"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total": [
                        {
                            "date": "2020-06-30",
                            "value": "114.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2019-06-30",
                            "value": "95.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2018-06-30",
                            "value": "70.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2017-06-30",
                            "value": "56.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2016-06-30",
                            "value": "52.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2015-06-30",
                            "value": "94.000000"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Research & Development": [
                        {
                            "date": "2020-06-30",
                            "value": "63.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2019-06-30",
                            "value": "29.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2018-06-30",
                            "value": "32.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2017-06-30",
                            "value": "51.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2016-06-30",
                            "value": "104.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2015-06-30",
                            "value": "52.000000"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Depreciation/Amortization": [
                        {
                            "date": "2020-06-30",
                            "value": "17.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2019-06-30",
                            "value": "12.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2018-06-30",
                            "value": "12.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2017-06-30",
                            "value": "16.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2016-06-30",
                            "value": "21.000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2015-06-30",
                            "value": "29.000000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
}
```

I am trying to restructure the json object so that it looks something like this:

```
{ "annual": {
    "2020-06-30": {
        "Revenue":"12820.000000",
        "Total Revenue":"12820.000000",
        "Cost of Revenue, Total":"5742.000000",
        "Gross Profit":"7078.000000",
        "Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total":"114.000000",
        "Research & Development":"63.000000",
        "Depreciation/Amortization":"17.000000"
    },
    "2019-06-30": {...},
    "2018-06-30": {...},
    "2017-06-30": {...},
    "2016-06-30": {...},
    "2015-06-30": {...}
    }
}
```

I am relatively new to using JSON with python and I am wondering if there is an efficient way to achieve this?

I have tried converting to a dataframe but I end up with a dataframe that has dictionary objects which needs to be parsed within multiple loops.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Paste the code you wrote and the problem you are facing in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

data = json.loads(json_data)
res = defaultdict(dict)

for k, v in data['annual'].items():
    for x in v:
        res[x['date']][k] = x['value']
        
res = {'annual': res}
print(json.dump(res))
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "annual": {
    "2020-06-30": {
      "Revenue": "12820.000000",
      "Total Revenue": "12820.000000",
      "Cost of Revenue, Total": "5742.000000",
      "Gross Profit": "7078.000000",
      "Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total": "114.000000",
      "Research & Development": "63.000000",
      "Depreciation/Amortization": "17.000000"
    },
    "2019-06-30": {
      "Revenue": "9965.000000",
      "Total Revenue": "9965.000000",
      "Cost of Revenue, Total": "5115.000000",
      "Gross Profit": "4850.000000",
      "Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total": "95.000000",
      "Research & Development": "29.000000",
      "Depreciation/Amortization": "12.000000"
    },
    "2018-06-30": {
      "Revenue": "6887.000000",
      "Total Revenue": "6887.000000",
      "Cost of Revenue, Total": "4930.000000",
      "Gross Profit": "1957.000000",
      "Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total": "70.000000",
      "Research & Development": "32.000000",
      "Depreciation/Amortization": "12.000000"
    },
    "2017-06-30": {
      "Revenue": "8447.000000",
      "Total Revenue": "8447.000000",
      "Cost of Revenue, Total": "4888.000000",
      "Gross Profit": "3559.000000",
      "Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total": "56.000000",
      "Research & Development": "51.000000",
      "Depreciation/Amortization": "16.000000"
    },
    "2016-06-30": {
      "Revenue": "7083.000000",
      "Total Revenue": "7083.000000",
      "Cost of Revenue, Total": "5064.000000",
      "Gross Profit": "2019.000000",
      "Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total": "52.000000",
      "Research & Development": "104.000000",
      "Depreciation/Amortization": "21.000000"
    },
    "2015-06-30": {
      "Revenue": "8574.000000",
      "Total Revenue": "8574.000000",
      "Cost of Revenue, Total": "7427.000000",
      "Gross Profit": "1147.000000",
      "Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total": "94.000000",
      "Research & Development": "52.000000",
      "Depreciation/Amortization": "29.000000"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with JSON. JSON is just a representation format.

You will need to parse the JSON data into an object in memory, then perform transformation into another object in a programming language of your choice. You will have to write an algorithm for this transformation yourself. You don't need dataframe for this, a simple dictionary/list is enough, with a library/module for JSON parsing and formatting.